# Is there a point to the 'returning' tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are <strike>138</strike> <strike>71</strike> <strike>21</strike> **0** questions with the tag [returning](/questions/tagged/returning).

Just in the first page of questions, I saw it being used for questions about returning values from a function in 10 different languages (usually "Why is my function returning the wrong thing?"), getting an identity / sequence value back from a SQL server after inserting (where it's at least an actual keyword being used), adding a "back" button to a webpage, troubleshooting getting a 404 or other error from a web request, and breaking out of a loop early.

I understand the reluctance to kill tags that refer to a specific command *and are actually used on questions about that command* but questions about the actual `RETURNING` SQL keyword make up **maybe** 10% of those questions.

The tag adds no useful information about the question whatsoever. Can we please kill it?

EDIT: Charles has proposed [sql-returning](/questions/tagged/sql-returning) as a replacement for questions that are actually about the SQL keyword, which should be less prone to misuse.

Comment: Get to retagging.

Comment: K, I just did like ---20--- 40 retaggigns, if 5 people do the same we can get rid of this tag.

Comment: Ok, I've done 60 and I'm satisfied, if you read this just go there and retag 10 questions, it only takes 30 seconds of your time :)

Comment: How's [tag:sql-returning] sound for the `RETURNING` clause?

Comment: Proposition: when you edit a post to remove the tag, don't just remove it - use the opportunity to fix some other things in the post also.

Comment: [tag:sql-returning] is now a thing.  About half of the SQL-related "returning" questions were relevant to it.  The rest, not so much.

Comment: I hope the tag won't be [tag:returning] any time soon.

Comment: Yup. We've got it for now. No questions with this tag anymore.